# How to get the label of a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have the cypher query

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
```

I can get the labels of a and b fine line so

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN labels(a), labels(b)
```

But when I want the label of `r` using the same syntax

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN labels(r)
```

I get

```
Type mismatch: expected Node but was Relationship
```

How do I return the label of `r`, the relationship?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Neo4j, relationships don't have labels - they have a single type, so it would be:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN TYPE(r)
```

Comment: is there any reason to not call the type as label as well?

Comment: Typically, the term 'label' implies that the target can have more than one of them, and the term 'type' implies a single assignment - relationships can only be one thing, while nodes can be multiple things.  That said, two nodes may have multiple relationships, each of a different type.

Comment: I see. But why shouldn't a relationship have multiple labels?

Comment: Can you give an example of a relationship where multiple labels is more appropriate than multiple relationships, keeping in mind that relationships can themselves have properties?

Comment: I admit that I can't think of one now, but may someone have one use case? Why not let the users decide for themselves?

Comment: The main reason would be that one of the 'prices you pay' for NoSQL databases is that they are specialized. Yes, you can model a graph in a RDBMS- but you wouldn't get the optimizations and performance that a dedicated graph DB provides.  A side effects of this is that you end up being much more prescriptive in design.  Relationship paths can be optimized more if each has one type.  Is it a drawback? Absolutely.  Is it worth it? Almost always. Key word is 'almost'. If it's a deal breaker for your solution - see what else can solve your problem. Maybe you can reframe your needs as well.

Comment: This is interesting. Do you know any articles discussing this in depth? What keywords should I look for?